# Windows 10: some data in %AppData% randomly is getting deleted affecting apps like Chrome and Notepad++

Tags: windows, windows-10

Occasionally some of the data content in the %AppData% folder is being deleted. For example, in Chrome all my settings are gone and I have to resync everything. This includes other programs like Notepad++ that store configuration files that I'm working on. This randomly happens and I can't find a reason why. I can go on weeks without any issues, then every other day, etc.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? If its easier is there any way I can move chrome folder somewhere else?

Comment: Wait... what?! Your Appdata folder is randomly getting deleted (how?!)? Or do you mean Chromes directory is being removed from Appdata?

Comment: That folder does not get randomly deleted. Make sure you leave that folder alone.

Comment: @Caeleste I need to edit it; the content of chrome and notepad++ are deleted. The appdata is still there, probably other programs as well but these are the ones I use deaily.

Comment: @Ahdee - This machine connected to an Active Directory domain by chance?

Comment: @Ahdee That is a lot more understandable

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is use of a cleanup tool such as [Wise Disk Cleaner](https://www.wisecleaner.com/thanks-for-downloading-wisediskcleaner.html) or one of the [numerous alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/wise-disk-cleaner/).

In the image below, note that *Other Applications* has been expanded and *Notepad++* is *not* checked, thereby keeping its settings, tabs and MRU (Most Recently Used list) intact.

Also adjust *Web Browser Trace* and *Cookies* settings to preserve or delete those. You can also create additions and exceptions to the list of items to clean.

[image: Wise Disk Cleaner options]

If you are not cleaning up the machine periodically, and have not set a cleanup app to run on its own, someone else might be doing this, or it might be a corporate policy to do so.

Workaround until you find the cause: Store data in the application directory, i.e., as if it were a portable application. For example, in *Notepad++*, change the location of configuration files in [Settings -> Cloud](https://helgeklein.com/blog/changing-the-location-of-notepad-configuration-files/).

Comment: good points. I thought it was ccleaner so I removed it but problem still persists. You are correct - I'm going to change location for notepad++ and find a way to do it for chrome. thanks

Comment: Is anyone else sharing your PC, and cleaning up tracks ;-)